# fgets set to char * causes segmentation fault, Dynamic string

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, scanf, gets

I'm writing a program in c that looks through a standardly inputted text file with lines "string int". I had the program running fine with scanf originally, but now the name has to be a dynamic string(size known at runtime) and when I switched the name in grade_entry to a pointer it started segmentation faulting

```
typedef struct grade_entry {
       char *name;
       int grade;
} grade_entry;

struct grade_entry grade_list[100];

int main(){
    int grade;
    int done;
    int i=0;
    do{
            puts("not weee\n");
            done=(int)strlen(gets(grade_list[i].name));
            puts("weee\n");
    }while(1);
}
```

compiles and current output is:

```
not weee

segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

**Resolved:
 I allocated the pointer and then reallocated for size+1, adding the null to
The end. It's unfortunate that I can't malloc immediately based off of the temp memory for scanf,fgets,gets. Oh well, thank you everyone for the help

Comment: I bet you haven't `malloc`ed memory for `grade_list[i].name`.

Comment: Your question title references function `fgets`, but your code only references `gets`.  Regardless, you have not allocated memory to the `char* name` field, but are storing values in this memory, which you do not "own".

Comment: Yeah array grade_list is not declaired and no memory allocated to each of the name in the each element in that array.

Comment: Grade-list is there and Ot started as scanf then gets and the fgets. This is from the gets attempt. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to allocate memory to `grade_entry.name`, otherwise it is a char pointer pointing to an arbitrary memory location and writing to it is causing segmentation fault.

Comment: if I allcocate it, it will have a set size though right? I need the string to match the input size

Comment: @Cman131 That's what happens when you use an ancient, obsolete programming language. Allocate a fixed size temporary buffer large enough to hold the names you expect (yes, that puts an arbitrary limit on their size), use `fgets` to read no more than the size of that buffer, then allocate the memory using `strlen` to find out the length of the name (don't forget to include room for the NUL). Or write a function that dynamically allocates enough space to hold any size line, or find one of the existing libraries that has such a function.

Answer (score 1):

You have not allocated memory to the char* name field, but are storing values in this memory, which you don't own actually.

Along with that you are running an infinite loop and playing with the same array element(Not incrementing the 'i')

Following is the code that will work I guess.

```
typedef struct grade_entry {
   char *name;
   int grade;
} grade_entry;

int main(){
int grade;
int done;
char str[100];
grade_entry grade_list[10];
int i=0;    
do{
        puts("not weee\n");
        gets(str);
        grade_list[i].name=(char*)malloc(strlen(str));
        done=strlen(grade_list[i++].name);
        puts("weee\n");
  }while(i<10);
}
```

Comment: Your memory allocation is 1 byte short; it should be `malloc(strlen(str)+1)`.  It also isn't clear that you ever copy the string into the allocated space — maybe just as well since you didn't allocate enough space, but a tad wasteful of effort and apt to lead to surprises later.

Comment: Yeah I need to do malloc(strlen(str)+1) and should have copied the string too. Thanks Jonathan for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The fault lies here:

```
        done=(int)strlen(gets(grade_list[i].name));//Storing in a unallocated memory using an uninitialized pointer. BAD!
```

Besides in your code I nowhere see you incrementing/decrementing/changing the value of `i`, so basically you will be overwriting `grade_list[0].name` everytime the loop executes. That's bad too. Too much memory leak!!

And its an infinite loop with no break condition!

Try something like this:

```
char buffer[MAX_LENGTH_OF_A_STRING];
memset(buffer,0x00,MAX_LENGTH_OF_A_STRING);
do{
        puts("not weee\n");
        done=strlen(gets(buffer));//This is enough
        grade_list[i].name=malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
        strncpy(grade_list[i].name,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1);
        memset(buffer,0x00,MAX_LENGTH_OF_A_STRING);
        i++;//You were not doing this
        puts("weee\n");
        //Put some condition to break this infinite loop, somewhere within the loop
}while(1);
```

Comment: Note that `malloc(strlen(buffer))` is a problem; you must also allocate space for the trailing `'\0'` which `strlen()` doesn't count.  Your `strncpy()` prevents that from overflowing, but doesn't null terminate the string.  Your `memset()` operations are unnecessary.

Comment: Don't you think that typecast as (char*) is required when your doing malloc.?

Comment: Before I could post my answer, my internet went down. :( Anyways here's my complete updated answer.

Comment: @VallabhPatade: opinion is divided on the merits or otherwise of casting the result of `malloc()`. Were it C++, there'd be no debate; the cast is mandatory. If you compile with options conforming to C99 (so that functions must be declared or defined before they are used), there is precious little harm that can come from the cast. If you compile for C89 or pre-standard C, then the cast may conceal problems (because `malloc()` is not declared and is inferred to return `int`). I learned C on a system where the cast was mandatory: `char *` addresses used address bits that other pointers did not.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `gets()` — ever.  Pretend it does not exist.  Pretend it will blow up your computer if you use it.  Assume it will be used to crash your program — because it will.

The trouble is that you cannot tell `gets()` how much space it has to work with.

Use `fgets()` instead.  If you're worried about reading lines that are long, then you should hope your system has the POSIX 2008 function [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) which handles reading lines of arbitrary length for you.  You only have to deal with the array of character pointers, which is simpler.

In your program, the pointers will end up being copied to the pointers in your data structures.

It's all good clean fun; the crucial thing is to remember that if you didn't initialize the pointer, it points randomly, and you can't use a pointer safely until you know what it points to.  So, initialize your pointers to point somewhere, or to NULL to indicate that they point nowhere.  Never dereference a NULL pointer.